# How to get IP Address in ubuntu when installed using virtual box

Tags: networking, virtualbox, eclipse

I have installed `ubuntu 16.04` on my laptop using `Virtual box`. I have installed eclipse in it. I am doing some remote debugging for which I need to write the ip address of ubuntu in the code. When I run `ifconfig` it shows ip address `10.0.2.15`.

When I entered this ip address and started the process, it failed. Although I can ping using ubuntu. In windows I have ip address `192.168.1.127`. Can I get this series ip address in ubuntu.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe your firewall (check both host and VM) just blocks the request? Should be the one from ifconfig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please switch your `network settings` to `Bridged Adapter` in the Virtualbox, then run `ifconfig` and now you should be able to get in there. And if any firewall is present fix that too.

[image]

Comment: Afaik this might not always work since bridged network may not work e.g. if host is connected via WiFi sometimes

Comment: I use it with `wifi` at times and it works

Comment: Yeah I know m too but sometimes it doesn't ;)